# read datatable rows and insert them into text file

Tags: text-files, datarow

I want to write to a text file all of the rows from a table (which contains only one column).

This is what I have:

```
try
            {
                DateTime DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(AppVars.IntegrationFilesLocation + DateTime.ToString(DateFormat) + " Detail.txt"))
                {
                    DataTable table = Database.GetDetailTXTFileData();

                    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(row[0].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
```

The above is not writing to the text file. It jumps from table.Rows to outside the foreach block. Basically it's not reading the row. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed. There was an issue with the query itself.